# Is Borderlands progress saved in LAN games?

Tags: borderlands

When playing Borderlands on PC/Steam via LAN (two people) is the mission progress saved as if you were playing a single player game?

Would I be able to go through the game, and get the same progress from beginning until end within the same LAN game? Even being able to shut the game and PC down when I am done, and resuming where we left off?

Comment: I haven't played LAN games, so I can't say with 100% certainty, but when I played a multiplayer game via Gamespy with my friends, the host (and anyone else who was at the same level of story progression) all progressed as though they were playing single-player (with the only caveat that the host got to choose what mission was being displayed on-screen). That means that any one of us turning in the mission counted as all of us turning in the mission, and we all got (roughly) equal mission rewards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Borderlands, game progress is stored *with your character*. In multi-player games, quest availability is based on the character that started/hosted the game session.

In short, if you play a 2 player game and you both always use the same characters then you should have no issues with progressing through the campaign.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Borderlands progress is saved in LAN games.

I'll admit, I've never played via LAN, but from my extensive experience with the save system and online gameplay, I have no idea why it would differ. It should be the same as split-screen gameplay, and I haven't heard of any-issue-like-that-of-which-you-speak from there either.